# PHP program which extracts attribute lists from custom tag

Tags: php, php5

PHP program which extracts attribute list from the custom tag. It also strips out the single and double quote if it exists around attribute value.

```
<?php

function parseAnswerTag($tag)
{
    // input => <answer scale="10" points="7">
    // ouput => ["scale"=>10, "points"=>7]
    // get the answer tag and parse out the attributes of answer tag
    $returningObj = array();
    //get the splitted string as an array
    $arr = splitByDelimiter(array('delimiter' => " ", 'string'=> $tag));
    // sliced the array to just have attributes otherwise will have answer element too
    foreach (array_slice($arr, 1) as $key => $value)
    {
        $arr[$key] = splitByDelimiter(array('delimiter' => "=", 'string'=> $value)); 
        if(in_array('scale', $arr[$key]) or in_array('points', $arr[$key]))
        {
            // check to see if single or double quote exist in value of key
            if(preg_match("/['\"]/",$arr[$key][1]))
            {
                // makes a call to strip out the quotes
                $returningObj[$arr[$key][0]] = stripQuotes($arr[$key][1]); 
            }
        }
    }
    // returns the associate key of attribute in the tag
    return $returningObj;
}

function stripQuotes($str)
{
    // input => "10"
    // output => 10
    // gets attribute with value and returns unquote string
    var_dump(strpos($str, "'") === FALSE);
    $start_point = 0;
    $end_point = 0;
    if(strpos($str, "'") !== FALSE)
    {
        $start_point = strpos($str, "'");
        $end_point = strpos($str, "'", $start_point+1);
    }
    elseif (strpos($str, '"') !== FALSE) 
    {
        $start_point = strpos($str, '"');
        $end_point = strpos($str, '"', $start_point+1);
    }
    return substr($str, $start_point+1, $end_point - ($start_point+1));
} 

function splitByDelimiter($input)
{
    //gets a associate array with delimiter and string {text value to be splitted}, split them by passed delimiter and return them
    // $input['delimiter'] => value splitted by and $input['string'] => value to be splitted
    return explode($input['delimiter'], $input['string']);
}
```

Can you please give me some constructive suggestions so that I can improve?

Comment: Can you add an example usage? It would also be great if you could add a bit more description. Eg what is a tag in this case, exactly? How does it look?

Comment: Your input and output in lines 2 and 3 don't seem to match. Output doesn't include `scale` attribute. Is this intended?

Comment: I also notice that 'scale' and 'points' are hard-coded in `parseAnswerTag`. Does that mean that these are the only attributes you care to parse?

Comment: I would like at DOM manipulation not parsing tags as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My function does not use hard-coded attributes, so it is more flexible than yours. It's also just a few lines of code (I think you made things over-complicated by having very thin wrappers for `explode` and `trim`.

```
function parseAttributesFromTag($tag){
    //The Regex pattern will match all instances of attribute="value"
    $pattern = '/(\w+)=[\'"]([^\'"]*)/';

    //preg_match_all used with the PREG_SET_ORDER flag will build an array
    //for each attribute-value pair present and put it in $matches. eg:
    /* with tag <answer scale='10' points="23">
    Array (
        [0] =>(
                [0] => scale='10
                [1] => scale
                [2] => 10
              )
        [1] => (
                [0] => points="23
                [1] => points
                [2] => 23
            )
    )
    */
    preg_match_all($pattern,$tag,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $result = [];
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $attrName = $match[1];

        //parse the string value into an integer if it's numeric,
        // leave it as a string if it's not numeric,
        $attrValue = is_numeric($match[2])? (int)$match[2]: trim($match[2]);

        $result[$attrName] = $attrValue; //add match to results
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This will turn `<tagname attr1="value1" attr2='value2'>` into `[attr1=>value1, attr2=>value2]`.  Unlike the other answer, this function supports spaces in attribute value and I have casted the value into a numeric type when it's really a number rather than a string

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things I noticed:

1. The function `splitByDelimiter()` is no more than a wrapper around `explode()`. Why not use `explode()` directly?
2. The function `stripQuotes($str)` can be a lot shorter: `trim($str," '\"");`. Note: You should never use `'` or `"` inside attributes, use their HTML equivalents.
3. Inside `parseAnswerTag()` you use a `foreach` loop. Inside it you assign values back into `$arr`, but under the wrong keys because `array_slice()` will have generated new numeric keys.
4. I don't understand why you select for `scale` and `point`?

I'm sorry but I cannot help you with other details, because I'm unsure about the origin of the HTML, and what you exactly are trying to accomplish. I did make a shorter version of your function:

```
function parseAnswerTag($tag)
{
    $inside = trim($tag,'<> ');
    $input  = explode(' ',$inside);
    array_shift($input);
    foreach ($input as $attr)
    {
        $parts = explode('=',$attr);
        $name  = trim($parts[0]);
        $value = trim($parts[1]," '\"");
        $output[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $output;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(parseAnswerTag('<answer scale="10" points="7">'));
echo '</pre>';
```

So trimming can be very useful.

Keep in mind: Algorithms like these are almost always slightly flawed. A simple thing like a double space could trip it up. It's very hard to get it completely right. Especially if you make it complicated or use regular expressions.

I also have to point out that PHP has a build in DOM to deal with HTML code. You can load HTML into it, and manipulate it there. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

In more complex cases this is the preferred way to deal with HTML.

Comment: I like your solution; it's easy to follow. One point though: we don't know much about the types of values the OP expects to handle, but he or she should be aware that if there is a space character in the attribute value, this function will fail to parse it properly (it assumes that all spaces demarcate attribute-value pairs

Comment: Yes, splitting on spaces and assuming that you get nice name-value pairs is unlikely to work in practice. Preferably use some prebuild DOM stuff, for it has already solved all these problems. I only intended the code as an example that does the same thing, but with simpler code. Giving a DOM example would, I think, go beyond what was asked in the question.